# How to get yielded value from cy.origin for external usage

Tags: cypress

I've been reading the cypress origin [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Yielding-a-value) about getting the value from origin and be used outside of it but I am encountering the issue where it returns undefined.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Add an alias for the text found inside the `.within()` and use it to set the correct subject at the end of the `cy.origin()` block.

```js
cy.origin(...
  ...
  cy.get(...).iframe().within(() => {
    cy.get('div').eq(7).children('p')
      .invoke('text').as('mailText')     // save to alias 
  })
  cy.get('@mailText')                    // set as "subject" on last line of origin
})
.should('eq', 'some-text-from-mail')
```

---

#### Longer explanation

It looks like you are on the right track in debugging (clicking on log) the `.invoke()` command.

That indicates that the element inside the `<iframe>` was found, but the `.within()` is preventing the text of `<p>` element from passing outside `cy.origin()`.

The [.within()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Yields) command yields same subject it is given

> **Yields**
>
> - `.within()` yields the same subject it was given

so the `cy.origin()` tries to pass back the `<iframe>`.

But if you looks at [.origin() - Yielding a value](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Yielding-a-value), we can see from the "incorrect" example that yielding an element doesn't work

> ```js
> cy.origin('https://example.cypress.io', () => {
>   cy.visit('/')
>   cy.get('h1') // Yields an element, which can't be serialized...
> }).contains('CYPRESS') // ...so this will fail
> ```

which explains why the message says "expected `undefined` to not equal `Cypress`".

---

#### Avoid asserting a negative

When you use `.should('not.eq', 'CYPRESS')` you are asserting a negative, but in this case it's the wrong approach.

You should change that to a positive assertion like `.should('eq', 'some-text-from-mail')`.

In this case you were lucky that `undefined` was being passed back, which fails on ***type***.

But if it had been some other text, the test would have incorrectly passed.

Comment: Thank you @Aladin Spaz, I just did a mock assertion to display that it is returning undefined. I tried using alias before but encountered an error that no alias found.

Comment: Yes, I think if you try to use an alias that was set inside the origin on the outside, it doesn't work. But doing `cy.get('@mailText')` inside the origin works because it creates the correct `subject`.

Comment: Another way might be to change `.within(...)` to `.find('div').eq(7).children('p').invoke('text')`, then the subject is automatically set to the text of that element

Comment: This is much better too simple and clean, I'll note this format for future use :)